# String is getting cut off in Java

Tags: java

Whenever I process an input string with the Scanner and the string contains a space, only the first word appears. How can I adjust this so the entire phrase is entered into one string variable?

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.next();
        String namefinal = name.replace(' ', '_');
        System.out.println(namefinal);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 9):

try `scan.nextLine()` instead of `scan.next()`

Comment: +1 he has to use it twice : `scan.nextLine();String name = scan.nextLine();` :)

Answer (score 8):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace

Source: [Scanner Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to do it in one step, you'll have to either implement you own reader or use `JOptionPane`. Here is an example

public class HelloWorld {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
    System.out.println(name);

}
```

}